# How to find CPU by needed parameters?

Tags: pcb-design, cpu

I trying to find a low-power processing unit with lowest price for some practical research. I trying to made a simple device with 1 SATA 3.0, 1 microSD and 1 USB 3.0 interfaces.

Can someone advise where I can search such CPU by such parameters?

I'am a newbee in PCB design, but I'am very interested in this field.

Comment: This would be a high end CPU. Two problems: 1) you generally can't purchase this type of CPU in small quantities, let alone the other ancilliary components 2) this is a major project, not a simple device, even before considering software. You need a lot of experience and tooling to get this to work with a processor of the level you're describing. Sorry to bring bad news!

Comment: As noted, this would be a somewhat high end device, but there may well be development kits available that you could study. These often have schematics and layout details from which you can study the various skills required.

Comment: Typical device: https://www.nxp.com/products/processors-and-microcontrollers/arm-based-processors-and-mcus/qoriq-layerscape-arm-processors/qoriq-layerscape-1012a-low-power-communication-processor:LS1012A?&tid=vanLS1012A

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can search on Digikey.

Although, USB 3.0, SATA 3.0 we will need some sort of good CPU which will have external RAM.

This is high speed, high density, complex, BGA, length and impedance matching routing and this is, by far, not something you should try as a beginner in PCB layout and you would probably not succeed.

This requires a lot of knowledge, expensive software, expensive testing hardware and lot of experience and usually is done by a whole team of engineer.

Check if you can lower down the specs, USB 2.0, SD Card is okay with a normal microcontrôleur.

If you really need to have those sort of specs, you can check on the Raspberry type of devices (although no USB 3.0 and I'm not sure about SATA).

This is what CPU routing looks like, and this is lower spec than you require
[image]

[Source](http://rhombus-tech.net/freescale/iMX6/news/)

---

You better find a board that is already made.

[Here is one](https://www.mouser.ch/new/Intel/intel-aero-compute-board/) that could fit your requirements, although it uses M.2 for the drive.